# Android OnScrollListener doesnt work correctly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add an infinite scroll to my Android Application but the onScrolled method doesnt work correctly I think so.

It will be called only once if I call the addOnScrollListener. But I think it should be called every time the RecyclerView has been scrolled.

```
    linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerViewNeuheiten.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager//LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerViewHistory.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerViewBestSeller.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerViewFavorites.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)


    recyclerViewNeuheiten.adapter = neuheitenAdapter
    recyclerViewHistory.adapter = historyAdapter
    recyclerViewBestSeller.adapter = bestsellerAdapter
    recyclerViewFavorites.adapter = favoriteAdapter

    //setRecyclerViewScrollListener()
    setRecyclerViewScrollListener()


    private fun setRecyclerViewScrollListener() {
            Log.v("scroll", "set listener")

            recyclerViewNeuheiten.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
                    Log.v("scroll", "onScrollStateChanged newState $newState")
                }

                override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                    Log.v("scroll", "onScrolled !!!!!")

                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                    val currentItem = recyclerView.layoutManager!!.childCount
                    val totalItemCount = recyclerView.layoutManager!!.itemCount
                    Log.v("scroll", "currentItem $currentItem")
                    Log.v("scroll", "totalItemCount $totalItemCount")
                    Log.v("scroll", "lastVisibleItemPosition $lastVisibleItemPosition")
                    Log.v("scroll", "scroll out items ${linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()}")
                }
            })
      }
```

Comment: all seems ok are you sure that you are setting the scroll listener to the right recyclerView?  if yes so if your recycler view contains item when you are scrolling it should notify the onScrolled method try the latest version of recyclerview 
i see some problem in your onScrolled method you are trying to log currentItem or totalItemCount variable but you haven't define them try with the debugger and add a breakpoint to the first line of the code inside the onScrolled method and go forward line by line until the end of the method and check the codes for any exception

Comment: Thank you but I think the biggest problem is that the onScolled method should be called every time I scroll. I have 20 items in my list, so I can scroll two or three times. But the "onScrolled !!!!" will never be called after the first time.

Comment: So I think it work. The Listener is connected to the right recyclerView.

currentItem gives me 20 back and totalItemCount 20 also. findFirstVisibleItemPosition returns 0 and I think this should be refreshed after every scroll. But it doesnt.

Comment: onScrolled method should be called nearly in each pixel you have scrolled but i think when for the first time gets invoked some sort of exception is occurring in your code that you have written in the onScrolled method and it leads to the problem that makes the onScrolled method to be not invoked again  because of this i suggested using debugger

Comment: But if I comment out everything from the method, the problem still exists. So I only have the super.onScrolled line inside my onScrolled now, but the Log will only called once.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I am using my RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView. The onScrolled method triggers each scroll without a ScrollView.

Comment: What was the fix for this? I'm having the same issue.